# Как получить случайное число в заданном промежутке на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа

Задача: нужно на JavaScript написать функцию `selfrandom(a,b:int):int` которая возвращяет случайное число в промежутке с a до b
например: `selfrandom(12,396);` возвращяет 254

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function selfRandom(min, max)
{
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

источник: [Справочник javascript: Math.random](http://javascript.ru/Math.random)

Answer (score 0):

Случайное число от 0 до 1: `Math.random()`

Округление числа:

1. До большего: `Math.round( 1.1 ) = 2`
2. До ближайшего: `Math.ceil( 1.5 ) = 2, Math.ceil( 1.1 ) = 1`
3. До меньшего `Math.floor( 1.9 ) = 1` либо `~~( 1.9 ) = 1`

Объявление функции 2х переменных:

```
function my_fn ( a, b ){
  var res = 0;
  //действия
  return res;
}
```