# Задача на Javascript

Tags: javascript

Создайте 50-значное поле со случайными номерами от -50 до 100 (включая предельные значения) и распечатайте его.
Создайте новое поле с именем sortedNumber, в котором вы вводите числа из заданного поля остортировав от наивысшего до самого маленького и распечатываете его.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432369/178988

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/66866/178988

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = Array(50).fill().map(x => (Math.random()*151 | 0) - 50)
var b = [...a].sort((x,y) => x-y)

console.log(a.join(" "))
console.log(b.join(" "))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: наверное, лучше вот так: `var a = Array.from({ length: 50 }, x => (Math.random() * 151 | 0) - 50)`